# Can't manage to call is_unsigned on the underlying_type of an enum class template parameter

Tags: c++, std, c++20, enum-class

I'm attempting to limit the use of this function to enum classes that have unsigned underlying types (and have `AddSubtract` as an enumeration) but I cannot for the life of me figure out the correct syntax.

```
template <class E>
concept EnumAddSubtract =
 std::is_enum_v<E> &&
 std::is_unsigned<std::underlying_type<E>::type> && //ERROR HERE
 requires() { {E::AddSubtract}; };

template <EnumAddSubtract E>
constexpr E operator+(E const & lhs, int const & rhs) {
    return static_cast<E>(static_cast<std::underlying_type<E>::type>(lhs) +
 static_cast<std::underlying_type<E>::type>(rhs));
}
```

I'm able to call `is_unsigned` on `underlying_type<>::type` in other contexts, such as:

```
enum class C : unsigned {};
std::cout << std::is_unsigned<std::underlying_type<C>::type>::value << '\n';
```

Comment: Please provide the minimal complete example (with all `#include`s) and full compiler's message

Comment: a) either [`typename` before `std::underlying_type<>::type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) or use `underlying_type_t`; b) `is_unsigned_v`, not `is_unsigned`; c) no parens after `requires`.

Comment: @yeputons that should be posted as an answer rather than a comment

Comment: @yeputons b ;) I guess `typename` for dependent types has been relaxed for C++20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to take the value of is_unsigned. Using yeputons's suggestion to use helper function variants that end in _v and _t, here is code that compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
 
template <class E>
concept EnumAddSubtract = std::is_enum_v<E> && std::is_unsigned_v<std::underlying_type_t<E>> && requires() { {E::AddSubtract}; };

template <EnumAddSubtract E>
constexpr E operator+(E const & lhs, int const & rhs) {
    return static_cast<E>(static_cast<std::underlying_type<E>::type>(lhs) + static_cast<std::underlying_type<E>::type>(rhs));
}

enum class C : unsigned {};
typedef std::underlying_type<C>::type tester;
 
int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::is_unsigned<std::underlying_type<C>::type>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_unsigned<tester>::value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: "*use helper functions _v and _t*" Neither of those are "functions".